# Swift 3: Convert Array<Double> to Array<Float> extension

Tags: swift, compilation

```
extension Array where Element : Double {
    public var asArrayOfFloat: [Float] {
        return self.map { return Float(other:$0) } // compiler error
    }
}
```

I get a compiler error complaining about `Float(other:$0)` "Argument labels '(other:)' do not match any available overloads."  But, `$0` is a `Double`, and there is a `Float.init(other:Double)` initializer.  What's the problem?

EDIT: Changing to `Float($0)` creates a different compilation error: "Ambiguous use of 'init'", and has 16 candidates.

EDIT: `Float.init(other:Double)` originally suggested by compiler, snapshot: [image]

Answer (score 3):

The issue was with `where Element : Double` ... This needs to be rewritten as `where Element == Double` (notice the use of `==` instead of `:`) because `Double` is not a protocol but a type.  Now compilation works with `Float($0)` as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `other:` label. If there is an `init` override that uses that label (FWIW, I don't see one), then it's not a *required* label.